# analysing memory allocation in xcode

Tags: ios, memory

When doing some operation on the app I am able to see the memory graph on the xcode. But not able to trace out the location on the code which is responsible for the increase in memory.

OR if it is because of allocation of memory on some object, then need to find out that object.

Answer (score 2):

To find out more about allocated objects try instruments (Run option "Profile") and select "Allocation".

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For object level memory allocation trace you should use `Allocation` instruments.